# Process Data cube from job on SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ssas, olap-cube

I have an SQL Server Agent job on server(X) that has a step that is supposed to process a data cube on a remote server(Y).

Whenever I run the job it fails and says that server(X) does not have 
permission to process the Cube or it does not exist.  I believe I have the job set up correctly but how do I give access on server(Y) to server(X) to process the cube??  Below is the script I am using. with the "SQL Server Analysis Services Command"

```
<Batch xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine">
<Process xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:ddl2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2" xmlns:ddl2_2="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2003/engine/2/2" xmlns:ddl100_100="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2008/engine/100/100" xmlns:ddl200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200" xmlns:ddl200_200="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2010/engine/200/200" xmlns:ddl300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300" xmlns:ddl300_300="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2011/engine/300/300" xmlns:ddl400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400" xmlns:ddl400_400="http://schemas.microsoft.com/analysisservices/2012/engine/400/400">
<Object>
  <DatabaseID>Analysis Services Project1</DatabaseID>
  <CubeID>S2E</CubeID>
</Object>
<Type>ProcessFull</Type>
<WriteBackTableCreation>UseExisting</WriteBackTableCreation>
</Process>
</Batch>
```

When I go to add the server(x) to the admin role on server(Y) via object explorer I cannot find the server through check names button.  Please help.

Comment: You need to add whichever Domain account is used by the SQL Agent on Server X to the admin role on Server Y.

Comment: Yes I am trying to, in the error message it says that "mydomain\server(x)$" does not have permission.  However when I try to add server(x)$ to the admin role I can't find it in my list.

Comment: Sounds like a networking issue.  You might find help on dba.stackexchange or ServerFault.

Comment: If you launch SQL Server Configuration Manager on Server(x) what is the SQL Agent service account exactly?

Comment: The error states that "MYDOMAIN\ServerX$" does not have permission to process the object.  However it is being executed by NT Service\SQLSERVERAGENT.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found this as the answer to my question.  Create a proxy account and used that to Process the data cube.

[DBA StackExchange Question/Answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106950/process-data-cube-from-job-on-sql-server)